# Spelling error in stackapps register page

Tags: bug, status-completed, wording, stackapps

I think this:

> You'll also receive parameters for authentication users via OAuth 2.0.

Should say:

> You'll also receive parameters for *authenticating* users via OAuth 2.0.

---

[image: spelling]
https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register

Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo fixed in the codebase, will be pushed out in the next build.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Don't you mean "Thanks for report!"?